# 'list' object has no attribute 'shape'

Tags: python, list, numpy

how to create an array to numpy array?

```
def test(X, N):
    [n,T] = X.shape
    print "n : ", n
    print "T : ", T



if __name__=="__main__":

    X = [[[-9.035250067710876], [7.453250169754028], [33.34074878692627]], [[-6.63700008392334], [5.132999956607819], [31.66075038909912]], [[-5.1272499561309814], [8.251499891281128], [30.925999641418457]]]
    N = 200
    test(X, N)
```

I am getting error as

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

So, I think I need to convert my X to numpy array?

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Use [`numpy.array`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html) to use `shape` attribute.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> X = np.array([
...     [[-9.035250067710876], [7.453250169754028], [33.34074878692627]],
...     [[-6.63700008392334], [5.132999956607819], [31.66075038909912]],
...     [[-5.1272499561309814], [8.251499891281128], [30.925999641418457]]
... ])
>>> X.shape
(3L, 3L, 1L)
```

**NOTE** `X.shape` returns 3-items tuple for the given array; `[n, T] = X.shape` raises `ValueError`.

Comment: then what if I want to get value of n and T since I am converting code from matlab, which has function [n,T] = size(X);.

Comment: @sam, I don't know matlab. What is expected value (`N`, `T`) for the above array?

Comment: size(X) returns the size of matrix X in separate variables m and n in matlab. so [n,T] = size(X) will give size of array

Comment: @sam, I mean ... let me know that specific size for the given list. `9`, `3`?   `3`, `3`?

Comment: I mean matrix dimensions for example 3x3. in that case, n will be 3 and T will be 3

Comment: @sam, I don't understand why such value comes.  The array contains 9 numbers. 2 * 3 = 6 !

Comment: in this case it will be 3x3

Comment: @sam, To get `3,3`, use `X = np.array([[-9.035250067710876, 7.453250169754028, 33.34074878692627], [-6.63700008392334, 5.132999956607819, 31.66075038909912], [-5.1272499561309814, 8.251499891281128, 30.925999641418457]])` (No surrounding brakets for numbers)

Comment: @sam, Using `X.shape`. ;)

Answer (score 27):

Alternatively, you can use `np.shape(...)`

For instance:

```
import numpy as np
a=[1,2,3]
```

and `np.shape(a)` will give an output of `(3,)`

Answer (score 13):

```
import numpy
X = numpy.array(the_big_nested_list_you_had)
```

It's still not going to do what you want; you have more bugs, like trying to unpack a 3-dimensional shape into two target variables in `test`.

Answer (score 12):

İf you have list, you can print its shape as if it is converted to array

```
import numpy as np
print(np.asarray(X).shape)
```

Comment: np.shape(X) -- no need to convert the array

Answer (score 8):

list object in python does not have 'shape' attribute because 'shape' implies that all the columns (or rows) have equal length along certain dimension.

Let's say list variable a has following properties:

```
a = [[2, 3, 4]
    [0, 1]
    [87, 8, 1]]
```

it is impossible to define 'shape' for variable 'a'.
That is why 'shape' might be determined only with 'arrays' e.g.

```
b = numpy.array([[2, 3, 4]
    [0, 1, 22]
    [87, 8, 1]])
```

I hope this explanation clarifies well this question.

Answer (score 5):

If the type is list, use `len(list)` and `len(list[0])` to get the row and column.

```
l = [[1,2,3,4], [0,1,3,4]]
```

`len(l)` will be 2.

`len(l[0])` will be 4.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you have to import numpy library (refer code for making a numpy array).
`shape` only gives the output only if the variable is attribute of numpy library. In other words it must be a np.array or any other data structure of numpy.
E.g.

```
import numpy
a=numpy.array([[1,1],[1,1]])
a.shape
```

```
(2, 2)
```

Comment: This is actually the better answer.