# different type of 2d array in Python

Tags: python, arrays

I have this line that build a 2d array

```
ResultsArray = multilabel_binarizer.transform(results_df['result'])
```

when I get ResultsArray values I get this

```
ResultsArray
Out[104]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 1],
       ...,
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, ..., 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 1]])
```

When I try to build my own 2d array like this

```
a = [["A1","A2","A3"],["B1","B2","B3"],["C1","C2","C3"]]

a
Out[123]: [['A1', 'A2', 'A3'], ['B1', 'B2', 'B3'], ['C1', 'C2', 'C3']]
```

when I do the shape of the ResultsArray

```
ResultsArray.shape
Out[126]: (999, 25)
```

but for my array a

I get error

```
a.shape

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-127-d6da0fa94082>", line 1, in <module>
    a.shape

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

how to create an 2d array that has same properties as ResultsArray

Comment: `numpy array` has attribute `shape`, not python `list`

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['list' object has no attribute 'shape'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21015674/list-object-has-no-attribute-shape)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because what you're creating is a Python's `list` which does not have the `shape` attribute, while `multilabel_binarizer.transform` returns a `numpy.array`.

You can wrap your `list` in `numpy.array` to make it the same:

```
import numpy

a = numpy.array([["A1","A2","A3"],["B1","B2","B3"],["C1","C2","C3"]])
a.shape
```